# C# Execute sql query in backgroundworker

Tags: c#, winforms, backgroundworker

I have a winforms application that logs in a user by checking to see if their user privileges, username and password all match before logging in. The database currently only has three users for testing purposes.

The problem I'm facing is, whenever I attempt to log in, the program freezes for at least 30 seconds before logging in. I've searched everywhere to find a solution. I've tried a backgroundworker, however, that doesn't work for me either; maybe I'm using it wrong.

This is the code used to login

**frmLogins.cs**

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs ev)
{
    try
    {
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select count(*) from Logins where Username='" + txtUserName.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "' and Type='" + cbType.Text + "'", scon);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        sda.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter("Select Type from Logins where Username='" + txtUserName.Text + "' and Password='" + txtPassword.Text + "'", scon);
            dt1 = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dt1);

            //Check if user matches with admin then log them in
            if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Admin")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Logging Successful!";
                SnackBarTimer();

                Hide();
                AdminForm admin = new AdminForm();
                admin.Show();
            }

            //Check if user matches with secretary then log them in
            if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Secretary")
            {
                lblMessage.Text = "Logging Successful!";
                SnackBarTimer();

                Hide();
                frmMain main = new frmMain();
                main.Show();
            }

            //Check if user matches with employee then log them in
            if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Employee")
            {

            }
            lblMessage.Text = "Logging In...";
            SnackBarTimer();
        }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
        SnackBarTimer();
    }
    finally
    {
        scon.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you determined what's taking 30s? Did you do an analysis and it points to your SQL?

Comment: Seems like that SQL should not be slow unless you have millions of users and no index on user name or password (even then 30s is very high).  Some thoughts:  1) You do not need a DataTable to check the existence of a record; Use `ExecuteScalar` - 2) You can select the type in the first query rather than querying again to get the type, 3) Get a decent profiler (or at worst debug it, manually timing the calls) to make sure you know what the bottleneck is.  I'm betting it's somewhere in `SnackBarTimer()`

Comment: BTW. Somebody can event delete your database using SQL Injection attack. Do NOT use string concatenate creating sql query!

Comment: your issue its so normal, but you can use background workers for the task asyncronus , try use this example!! http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners

Comment: Your form is freezing because button code executes on the UI thread. Don't login from button code. Everything in the whole login process is executing on the same thread. What's `SnackBarTimer`?

Comment: Side note - Looks like you have a class variable for your `SqlConnection` named `scon` that you then dispose of in your method. This is bad practice! Create each `SqlConnection` when and where needed as late as possible and then close/dispose it immediately there after (in using block or finally). Connection pooling is handled automatically by Sql Server.

Comment: To figure out why a query is taking so long copy the query to Sql Management Studio and execute it manually. Take a look at the execution plan. You can also turn on statistics (SET STATISTICS IO ON). It is probably just a missing index, once added your query will run faster.

Comment: @D Stanley The `SnackBarTimer()` is a panel docked at the bottom of the form to be displayed and disappear after the timer is complete (like the snackbar in android). I'm fairly new at C#, while I do know what `ExecuteScalar` is, may I ask how it would be used instead of DataTable?

Comment: [Read the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx).  It executes a SQL command and returns a single value.

Comment: Your design also needs some tuning. Best practice is to have username be unique. Create a unique index on this name and return the user details just by this field alone in your query. You can use a [DataReader](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9kcbe65k(v=vs.110).aspx) for this. Then check the password in memory (ideally password is hashed and not stored in plain text). Finally do not forget to use sql parameters instead of string concatination. These changes should result in one sql call total.

Comment: @Igor Thank you, I'll follow those tips

Comment: @Brandon you said not to login from button code, which other way can I login? I've tried backgroundworker and can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @JeremyJames - Not discounting Brandon's suggestion but I would get your current method (including sql call and indexes) right first. Once you do that check the speed again, it is probably fine but if not then see if you can offload the login check from the UI thread.

Comment: How long does it take to open a connection to the database?

Comment: @Igor -  Okay, thank you for the help, I'll get that done and see if it is resolved

Comment: @JeremyJames I should rephrase: You totally *can* fire the login from the button, but don't actually execute the login in the button code. Use a controller that works in another thread to do the login. When it's finished, notify your UI that the login succeeded/failed. If you need some help with that, ask a separate question (do a search first, there's tons of threading questions on SO already) and someone will be glad to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't remove the lag, however I figured out how to properly implement the backgroundworker so now the form doesn't freeze up anymore. I also added a progressbar to show some form of progress.

Login Button Click Event:

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs ev)
    {
        //
        //If background worker busy, show snackbar and login after
        //
        if (!bgw.IsBusy)
        {
            pnlSnackBar.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = "Logging In...Please wait";
            SnackBarTimer();
            bgw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }            
    }
```

BackgroundWorker:

```
private void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            cmd = new SqlCommand("Select Type from Logins where Username='@user' and Password='@pass'", scon);

            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", txtUserName.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", txtPassword.Text);

            sda1 = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            dt1 = new DataTable();
            sda1.Fill(dt1);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //pnlSnackBar.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            SnackBarTimer();
        }
    }
```

BackgroundWorker Completed:

```
private void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (dt1.Rows.Count == 1)
            {
                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Admin")
                {
                    LoginInfo.UserID = txtUserName.Text;
                    Hide();
                    AdminForm admin = new AdminForm();
                    admin.Show();
                }

                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Secretary")
                {
                    LoginInfo.UserID = txtUserName.Text;
                    Hide();
                    frmMain main = new frmMain();
                    main.Show();
                }

                if (dt1.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "Employee")
                {
                    LoginInfo.UserID = txtUserName.Text;
                    Hide();
                    EmployeeForm employee = new EmployeeForm();
                    employee.Show();
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            pnlSnackBar.Visible = true;
            lblMessage.Text = ex.Message;
            SnackBarTimer();
        }
    }
```

Progress Changed:

```
private void bgw_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        metroProgressSpinner.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
    }
```